# How to Upload multiple Document (bulk) in Document DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have Documents list(object) that object has multiple documents i.e. Json records are present but while I try to upload that Bunches of Document(Records) it not upload on document DB but while I upload Single Document records it upload succesfully.

```
  List<MyModelClass> listObj = new List<MyModelClass>();
  Document doc = await DocumentClient.CreateDocumentAsync("dbs/" + DocumentDatabase.Id + "/colls/" + DocumentCollection.Id, listObj);
```

above code is not working.....

```
   foreach (var item in listObj )
    {
      Document doc = await Client.CreateDocumentAsync("dbs/" + DocumentDatabase.Id + "/colls/" + DocumentCollection.Id, item);
    }
```

This code is working for me.....

```
 Syntax : CreateDocumentAsync(String, Object, RequestOptions, Boolean)
 Object :- Document object // I Know it as per syntax it need to be "Document Type".
```

I want any Other way to Upload All Document at Once....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot insert more than one document at a time. The call to `CreateDocumentAsync()` is for single documents only.

To accomplish this, you'd need to devise some type of server-side stored procedure to accomplish this, and then pass your document array to the function in a single call. You may want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35512941/272109) to see how someone else solved this using a server-side function, by essentially creating an array of documents locally, and then walking through the array in their stored procedure. So, creating something like this (as excerpted from that answer):

```
docObject = {
  "items": [{doc}, {doc}, {doc}]
}
```

And passing `docObject` to your stored procedure.

Ultimately, your stored procedure would still be making individual insert calls, one per document. But... you would not have the multiple network round-trips. And the inserts would be transactional (if one of the inserts failed, or you threw an exception, the other inserts would be rolled back).

Comment: As per @david's answer, here's a sample of a bulk import stored procedure - https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/BulkImport.js

Comment: Thanks, David and Ryan, your answer really helpful for me.

Comment: Hey im getting issue to execute "ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync" method my executtion pointer goes to "ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync" method and then nothing can happens, not exception ...

Comment: @PravinSharma Please ask a new question, with specifics (e.g. your code).

Answer (score 4):

It is possible now to insert multiple documents at once by using **Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor** library

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-dot-net

Comment: An specific example of adding documents would be appreciated, not just the link.