# Azure CosmosDB batch insert

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have millions (about 200 million) records, which I need to insert into my `CosmosDb`.

I've just discovered that Microsoft failed to implement batch insert capability... [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36064068/596841), [(2)](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6435801-batch-operation-support) <--- 3 years to reply.

Rather than throw myself of a Microsoft building, I have started to look for alternative solutions.

One idea I had was to write all my documents to a file and then import that file into my DB.

Now, how, once I have created my JSON file containing my documents, can I do the bulk import (from Python 3.6)?

I've come across some [Migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data), but I was wondering if there is a better/quicker way and without me having to install this tool... You see, I will be running my code in a `WebJob`, so installing the migration tool may not be an option, anyway.

Comment: upvoted because the down voter left no comment

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `Mongo DB driver` which is supported by `Azure Document DB`.

`Mongo DB driver` works with the `binary` protocol, while `Azure Document DB SDK` works with the `HTTP` protocol.

As we know,work efficiency of binary protocol is better than HTTP protocol.

You could use **`Bulk`** method to import data into Azure Cosmos DB and each group of operations can have at most `1000` operations.
Please refer to the document [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/index.html).

***Notes:***

The maximum size for a document is `2 MB` in the Azure Document DB which is mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-resources#documents).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It seems I greatly overestimated the ability of Cosmos DB.