# Cosmos DB not saving all rows

Tags: database, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to import a large amount of data ~45k documents into a Cosmos collection.  Using

```
var doc = await client.UpsertDocumentAsync(coll, r);
```

Inside a loop where `r` is an individual element in the collection I have set a unique key to be one of the elements in the class and all have unique values.  No errors are returned and a check for `doc.StatusCod`e does not show any errors.  Problem is that only a small fraction of those rows are actually created (about 2000) per run.  The id property is being generated as a `GUID`.

I decided to try this against a SQL table where I perform inserts and load the primary key with the property I'm using as the unique key.  All 45000 rows are saved and no errors are encountered.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm now to Cosmos.

Comment: Can you show all the code for the processing?  I get that you have the upsert call there, but it's possible that there is an error in the surrounding code that's eating an error.  Also, what is the setup (e.g. RU/s) of your cosmos instance?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: So I rewrote the logic, made sure that each call had an "id" property and verified that data is being written.  I added try and catch around the code and no errors are being reported. I also changed the logic to ReadDocumentAsync first and then call CreateDocumentAsync. Still no errors, the code runs to completion but I only have a small fraction of the resulting rows I expect.

Comment: To follow-up on the comment I just wrote and to answer Brendan's question. The Cosmos db was setup with default RU/s, but it just seems silly that the code would silently fail to create data.  My "limited" understanding of how the api works is the call to "Upsert" is supposed to handle any issues where the RU/s are exceeded and silently retry the operation.
What should have been so simple has so far been a waste of time.  I changed the code to use SQL and it worked the first time.  I will post code that I have been using as a reference.

Comment: ``private static async Task Updatedb(IDocumentClient client,string dbName, string coll, List<RETSData> myRets)

        {
            foreach (RETSData r in myRets) // 500 elements
            {
              try
              {
                   var collUri = UriFactory.CreateCollectionUri(dbName, coll);
                   Document newdoc = await client.UpsertDocumentAsync(collUri, r);
                            
               } catch (DocumentClientException ne)
                 {
                   throw;  // never happens
                  }
     }
} 
``

Answer (score 0):

> No errors are returned and a check for doc.StatusCode does not show
>   any errors. Problem is that only a small fraction of those rows are
>   actually created (about 2000) per run.

Per my knowledge,cosmos db operations are affected by the [RU settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units).If your data is very large,you can't query them or operate them in one single batch. Continuation token is applied to making big size operation.You could get an idea of it about this [link](https://h-savran.blogspot.com/2019/04/introduction-to-continuation-tokens-in.html) and this [blog](https://medium.com/@gary.strange/understanding-cosmosdb-continuation-tokens-hasmoreresults-and-connectionpolicy-requesttimeouts-3ed1fadfa81d).

Actually,you could use official [Bulk Executor Lib](http://bulk%20executor%20library) to do the insert and update batch. Here are the [source codes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-bulkexecutor-dotnet-getting-started) for .net sdk. You could refer to this case:[Fastest way to insert 100,000+ records into DocumentDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744582/fastest-way-to-insert-100-000-records-into-documentdb)

> The id property is being generated as a GUID

Based on the [official statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.resource.id?view=azure-dotnet):

If an Id is not supplied by the user the SDK will automatically generate a new GUID and assign its value to this property before persisting the document in the database.

Comment: Hi Jay, I appreciate the time you took to respond and the information about inserting large amounts of data. I did change my code to use id but had the same behavior.